# Trigger click on vuejs slotted element within parent component

Tags: vue.js, click, slot

I've seen this answered many times where the goal was for the child component to respond to a click event, but I want the slotted element defined in the parent to manage the click event which should be within the scope of the parent. I don't want the child to manage the click because the child is merely to have consistent formatting. The click action will be unique to every use of the child component. As it stands, clicking the slotted `app-primary-options-option` element does not trigger the `onClick` event.

```
<template>
  <app-primary-options>
    <app-primary-options-option
      v-for="layer in layers"
      :key="layer.name"
      :value="layer.name"
      @click="onClick(layer.name)"
    >
      {{ layer.longText }}
    </app-primary-options-option>
  </app-primary-options>
</template>

<script>
  import AppPrimaryOptions from '../selectors/PrimaryOptions.vue'
  import AppPrimaryOptionsOption from '../selectors/PrimaryOptionsOption.vue'
  
  export default {
    methods: {
      onClick () {
        console.log('Clicked')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

AppPrimaryOptions child:

```
<template>
    <div class="options">
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>
```

AppPrimaryOptionsOption child:

```
<template>
  <div class="option">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `div` :

```js
Vue.component('AppPrimaryOptions', {
  template: `
  <div class="options">
    <slot />
  </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('AppPrimaryOptionsOption', {
  template: `
  <div class="option">
    <slot />
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  methods: {
    onClick (l) {
      console.log('Clicked', l)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      layers: [{name: 'a', longText: 'aaa'}, {name: 'b', longText: 'bbb'}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <app-primary-options>
    <app-primary-options-option
      v-for="layer in layers"
      :key="layer.name"
      :value="layer.name"
    >
      <div @click="onClick(layer.name)">{{ layer.longText }}</div>
    </app-primary-options-option>
  </app-primary-options>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I would prefer to have the entire div as clickable. I could force some of that with css on an A tag, but that seems to be a bit hacky. Is there a reason I can't watch for the event on the component itself?

Comment: Then put it in a div .)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I had concerns with requiring other developers to know the component would only work if the text was wrapped in a DIV.

Answer (score 0):

From VueJs:

> Event listeners passed to a component with v-on are by default only
> triggered by emitting an event with this.$emit. To add a native DOM
> listener to the child component's root element instead, the .native
> modifier can be used

```
  <app-primary-options>
    <app-primary-options-option
      v-for="layer in layers"
      :key="layer.name"
      :value="layer.name"
      @click.native="onClick(layer.name)"
    >
      {{ layer.longText }}
    </app-primary-options-option>
  </app-primary-options>
```

Incidently, this is provided on the [VueJS 3 migration documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#overview), as the native modifier was removed with this behavior now default.